# Why is my Footer not sticking?

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

I'm in the process of re-doing my site - It's being built as and when I have time - I'm having a bit of a problem with two of the four pages with regards to the footer - I'm not too sure why it's not working as it seems to be working alright on two of the pages. I'm using the technique from here: (ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)

I'm using these values in my CSS:

```
    /* BOTTOM BAR */

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -122px;
}

.push, .footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 122px;
}

.footer {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    clear:both;
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    border-top:1px solid #36383D;
}

.bottom_content {
    width: 900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-top: 25px;
    border: 0px;
}

.copywrite {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    clear: both;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:300;
    color: #3c3e43; 
}
```

- It's working fine on here: http://bit.ly/MlV6JP

But not on here: http://bit.ly/NfVoRR
Or the about page (/test/test_about.php)

I've tried a number of different things, but to no avail! Starting to tear my hair out a bit with it, so any advice would be massively appreciated

EDIT - Here is what I am seeing: [jameshenry.info/test/BottomExamples.png](http://jameshenry.info/test/BottomExamples.png) I'm seeing this in chrome, safari and also safari iOS. I want it to always sit on the bottom of the page, underneath the page content.

Comment: I don't see any difference between your examples, related to the footer…

Comment: I don;t see any difference either. What browser are you seeing the problem in? When you say you want the footer to stick do you mean so that it's always visible at the bottom of the browser (so that the rest of the page scrolls underneath it) or just that it always sits at the bottom of your page (under the rest of your page content)?

Comment: Really? How strange - Here is what I am seeing [link]http://www.jameshenry.info/test/BottomExamples.png

I'm seeing this in chrome, safari and also safari iOS. I want it to always sit on the bottom of the page, underneath the page content.

Comment: What size monitor do you have hj8ag?  The reason for the footer not sticking is likely an error in the html not the css.  Make sure your tags are properly closed and properly nested.

Comment: 24" @ 1920x1200, but also using iOS devices and a 23" @ 1920x1080 to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your HTML.

Here is an example of poorly nested tags in your source:

```
<a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery" href="../images/photography/fullsize/MVI_4003-2.jpg" width="249" height="148"><img src="../images/photography/thumbnail/MVI_4003-2-thumb.jpg"></div></a>
```

As you can see there is a closing div tag in your anchor that shouldn't be there.  Fix these kinds of errors and your footer should work as intended.

Comment: Just had a look at the code and swapped these tags around - I'm struggling to see any other incorrectly nested tags, especially on the about page (http://www.jameshenry.info/test/test_about.php)! 

Also, not sure why but on an iPad when rotated it seems to stick to the bottom of the page perfectly....

Comment: The only other thing that is popping out at me is that your `.push` div is not directly within your `.wrapper` instead it is nested in your `.content` div.  Move the `.push` to right below the `.content`

Comment: I've moved these outside the tags and still no joy! Really frustrated with the page now - I've tried also removing the '.wrapper' field like the page that's working (www.jameshenry.info/test/test_2.html) which also didn't work - so I've put this back for now

Comment: I've switched to the cssstickyfooter.com method - it just works... But thank you for all your help, you have helped me to correct and validate a lot of my code